# Extracting multiple tables/datasets from csv

Tags: python, loops

I have a small csv file that contains tables/datasets no larger than 50 rows each, and each separated with a blank row. An example of what the file looks like:

```
Info_header 1
Info_header 2
NaN
Title1, Title2
Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4,Column5,Column6,Column7,Column8
Steve,Indiana,0,0,2,1,2,5
Megan,New York,34,0,0,5,3,2
...
NaN
-Total-,,34,0,2,6,5,7
NaN
Title3,Title4
ColumnA,ColumnB,ColumnC,ColumnD,ColumnE,ColumnF,ColumnG,ColumnH
...
```

Row and column size change do change. Row with a single NaN represents the blank row. Since the tables are named, the loop I'm planning on using needs to start below the row with the title of the table:

```
df = read_csv('data.csv')

start_value = df.loc[(df[0] == "Title1")
                     & (df[1] == "Title2")]

start_value = (start_value.index + 1)

# my loop:

empty_list = []
for index, row in df.loc[start_value[0]].iteritems():
    if pd.isnull(row[1]):
        empty_list.append(df[row])
    else:
        break
```

My logic is if Title1 and Title2 meet my criteria, then append rows below the Title row, & stop appending if a row has no data. How can I do this? I also understand that using loops in dataframes isn't the best solution, alternatives solutions are welcome.

Comment: In your example, do you want to the line `Megan,New York,34,0,0,5,3,2` to be the last one of the dataframe?

Comment: @JulienRoullé No, the last row should be the row before an empty one. There's a row with a title, then anywhere between 10 - 50 rows for each table, but each separated by a blank row. The last row for the dataframe should be the one before the blank one.

Comment: 1. Imo as _"Row and column size change"_ it's not a good idea to try to load the whole file into one dataframe with read_csv. To be more precise this will fail. 2. I don't see any blank lines in your example data - and if NaN is meant to be them, they're not only between different blocks of data, but also right before the total line... So please, check and edit your post to be more precise.

Comment: but in this case, the line `Megan,New York,34,0,0,5,3,2` is the last line before the blank row, right?

Comment: @JulienRoullé sorry if the post isn't precise. that line you referenced above is the 2nd line in the first table. however, the ellipses indicate that the rows continue with similar data until the Nan row.

Comment: @SpghttCd if loading the csv file to a single dataframe is not a good idea, what would you suggest? And yes, the NaN line is meant to represent the blank line between tables, and I'm not too worried about adding that to a final dataframe as its a calculated row. Also, my apologies for the lack of precision in the post, this is my first one.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Can't this be broken down into two steps, splitting the data and parsing the CSV? Both of those are relatively trivial tasks.

Comment: @AMC the issue is separating the tables found in a single csv file, where each table is divided by a single blank row, and each table has a name in the first and/or the second column.

Comment: I think my approach would be to iterate through all lines of the file to get the data blocks between the empty lines. Each datablock can be read in with StringIO. See my answer for an example.

Comment: @KevinG Right, I knew that. I was hoping for something more specific. As I mentioned in my comment, the first thing I’d try is splitting the data into different files, and then parsing those. Had you tried that?

Comment: @AMC haven't even thought about that, but I'll definitely look into it

Comment: @KevinG I can't remember if I had already asked, but it would be good to have some example data that can be used for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I would do:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

with open('data.csv') as f:
    block = ''
    for line in f:
        block += line
        if not line[:-1]:
            if len(block.splitlines()) > 3:
                print(pd.read_csv(StringIO(block), skiprows=1))
            block = ''
```

---

Result if applied to your example data, given that NaNs are replaced by blank lines and the second block is completed with some data:

```
#   Column1   Column2  Column3  ...  Column6  Column7  Column8
# 0   Steve   Indiana        0  ...        1        2        5
# 1   Megan  New York       34  ...        5        3        2

# [2 rows x 8 columns]

#    ColumnA  ColumnB  ColumnC  ...  ColumnF  ColumnG  ColumnH
# 0        1        2        3  ...        6        7        8

# [1 rows x 8 columns]
```

Comment: Why all the `block` stuff, can't you just read the entire file at once and split on empty lines?

Comment: @AMC because this way the code iterates once over the whole file line by line, immediately checking if there is a block finished and puts it into a dataframe. If you on the other hand read the whole file into memory you have nothing done after already having read the whole file. And after that, you have to start splitting, which again needs to scan through the complete data. So IMO this here should be more efficient, but as I said: this is _my way_ - don't hesitate to write an approach according to your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you can "clean" your data before with `re` module (if you know the titles beforehand).

For example ([Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/msGPpr/1)):

```
txt = '''Info_header 1
Info_header 2

Title1, Title2
Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4,Column5,Column6,Column7,Column8
Steve,Indiana,0,0,2,1,2,5
Megan,New York,34,0,0,5,3,2

-Total-,,34,0,2,6,5,7

Title3,Title4
ColumnA,ColumnB,ColumnC,ColumnD,ColumnE,ColumnF,ColumnG,ColumnH
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7
'''

import re
from io import StringIO

df1 = pd.read_csv( StringIO(re.findall(r'^Title1.*?Title2(.*?)(?:\n\n|\Z)', txt, flags=re.M|re.S)[0]) )
df2 = pd.read_csv( StringIO(re.findall(r'^Title3.*?Title4(.*?)(?:\n\n|\Z)', txt, flags=re.M|re.S)[0]) )

print(df1)
print()
print(df2)
```

Prints:

```
  Column1   Column2  Column3  Column4  Column5  Column6  Column7  Column8
0   Steve   Indiana        0        0        2        1        2        5
1   Megan  New York       34        0        0        5        3        2

   ColumnA  ColumnB  ColumnC  ColumnD  ColumnE  ColumnF  ColumnG  ColumnH
0        0        1        2        3        4        5        6        7
```

Answer (score -1):

Data file contents:

```
Title 1,Title 2
Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4,Column5,Column6,Column7,Column8
Steve,Indiana,0,0,2,1,2,5
Megan,New York,34,0,0,5,3,2

Title 3,Title 4
ColumnA,ColumnB,ColumnC,ColumnD,ColumnE,ColumnF,ColumnG,ColumnH
val 1 A, val 1 B, val 1 C, val 1 D, val 1 E, val 1 F, val 1 G, val 1 H
val 2 A, val 2 B, val 2 C, val 2 D, val 2 E, val 2 F, val 2 G, val 2 H
```

Code:

```py
from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd

with open('../resources/temp_in.txt') as in_file:
    file_contents = in_file.read()

tables = []

for curr_str in file_contents.split('\n\n'):
    table_title, table_data = curr_str.split('\n', maxsplit=1)
    table_data = pd.read_csv(StringIO(table_data))
    print(f"{table_title}\n{table_data}\n")
    tables.append((table_title, table_data))
```

Output:

```
Title 1,Title 2
  Column1   Column2  Column3  Column4  Column5  Column6  Column7  Column8
0   Steve   Indiana        0        0        2        1        2        5
1   Megan  New York       34        0        0        5        3        2

Title 3,Title 4
   ColumnA   ColumnB   ColumnC  ...   ColumnF   ColumnG   ColumnH
0  val 1 A   val 1 B   val 1 C  ...   val 1 F   val 1 G   val 1 H
1  val 2 A   val 2 B   val 2 C  ...   val 2 F   val 2 G   val 2 H

[2 rows x 8 columns]
```